# Setting a textView equal to a value in an Array Java

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have written some simple code to generate a random value in my array. It generates that random value, but I cannot set my textView equal to that value. This is a very simple problem, but I can't seem to find the solution anywhere.

Here is my code...

```
final String[] group_topics = {"Walking", "Swimming", "Running"};

public void getRandomTopic1() {
    Random random = new Random();

    int index = random.nextInt(group_topics.length);

    topicOne.setText(group_topics[index]);



    topicOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
}
```

Comment: does it crash?? why are you setting text before referencing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
topicOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
 topicOne.setText(group_topics[index]);
```

At First You will have to wire the widget and then acess it . you doing it the other way which will not work. try this and it will work.

Comment: Omg I can't believe I didn't think of that thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You did not instantiate your TextView before setting a value to it. I have changed the code slightly.

```
final String[] group_topics = {"Walking", "Swimming", "Running"};

public void getRandomTopic1() {
    Random random = new Random();

    int index = random.nextInt(group_topics.length);

    topicOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    topicOne.setText(group_topics[index]);
```

}